# WKWebView Password AutoFill

Tags: swift, wkwebview, autofill

I've been trying to get around making this work for the past two days, but there has been no progress. I currently have an application loading with WKWebView using Swift, which is a login page. On Safari I was able to successfully utilise the autofill functionality, but it seems like that isn't possible using WKWebView, or I think at least?

According to Apple's documentation:

> 1. Set up your app’s associated domains. To learn how to set up your app’s associated domains, see Supporting Associated Domains.

> 2. Set the correct AutoFill type on relevant text fields. For an iOS app, see Enabling Password AutoFill on a Text Input View. For a web app, see Enabling Password AutoFill on an HTML Input Element.

I have done both steps and the password I saved on Safari for the login shows in the list of saved passwords in the Settings, but with the applications icon. Still, there is no option in the WKWebView's keyboard to select a password at all. It's just the keyboard itself, with the done and up/down (for the field selection) buttons.

[WKWebView's Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwElX.png)

[Keyboard using Safari to access the login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIh89.png)

I have tried everything till now, I just want to know if this is even possible or not. Any kind of guidance towards getting this to work, if there even is any, would be much appreciated.